# Plumber, notify and a custom error fucntion give me an Error in plugin 'plumber': Message: Can't pipe to undefined

Tags: javascript, gulp, plumber

I'm building a Wordpress theme starter app in node, gulp and also handlebars to create templates.

I'm having an issue with plumber, notify and gulp-sass plugins working together.

Here is a link to my repo:
https://github.com/elassol/wp-theme

every time I try to compile sass with my gulp task I get an error:

> Error in plugin 'plumber' Message:
>     Can't pipe to undefined

I have a Pumbler error function, a SASS TASK to preprocess sass and a gulp watch task to fire the sass taks when a file change.

```js
   

var gulp         = require('gulp');
var gutil        = require('gulp-util');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sass         = require ('gulp-sass');
var plumber      = require('gulp-plumber');
var notify       = require('gulp-notify'); 
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync'); 
var cache        = require('gulp-cache');
var imageOpt     = require('gulp-image-optimization');
var jshint       = require('gulp-jshint');
var useref       = require('gulp-useref'); 
var uglify       = require('gulp-uglify'); 
var gulpIf       = require('gulp-if');
var clean        = require('gulp-clean');
var cssnano      = require('gulp-cssnano');
var concat       = require('gulp-concat');
var del          = require('del');
var runSequence  = require('run-sequence');
var sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var fs           = require('fs'); 

// ==========================================================
// Pumbler error function
// ==========================================================


function customPlumber(errTitle) { 
  return plumber({
    errorHandler: notify.onError({
          // Customizing error title
          title: errTitle || "Error running Gulp",
          message: "Error: <%= error.message %>",
          sound: "Glass"
        })
    });
}


// ==========================================================
// STYLES TASK
// ==========================================================

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return  gulp.src(paths.styles.src + '**/*.scss')
       
        .pipe(customPlumber('Error Running Sass'))

        // inititalizr sourcemap before anyother pluging that alter  files
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['theme/bower_components'],
            precision: 2
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['ie 8-9', 'last 2 versions']
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.build))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload())
        
})

// ==========================================================
//  WATCH TASK
// ==========================================================
 
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], function(){ 
    gulp.watch(basePaths.src + 'sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(paths.scripts.src + '**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('theme/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('theme/js/**/*.js', ['jshint']);
})
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or at least point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**custom error function** doesn't throw the error. there is some **undefined pipe** at pipeline. <s>it seems undefined pipe at sourcemaps lines. u should require gulp-sourcemaps.</s>

---

after edit: in this case u should change

```
  .pipe(sync.reload());
```

line like this

```
  .pipe(sync.reload({stream:true}));
```

### additional explanion

in gulp task there should be a stream throught the pipeline. every pipe should return the stream object for pass the stream to next pipe.

at first version of your code; sync, broking the stream cycle because of reload method returns nothing. and gulp throwing an error for this reason. stream:true property try to inject the streams and returning the incoming stream back. this is it.

actually u can use sync.stream() instead of sync.reload(). or if u dont want to inject your styles u can apply like this example

https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/#gulp-reload

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I double check all my modules and requires and I have sourcemap, notify, autoprefixer so I still don't know what is undefined yet... any change to can throw some more light to the subject.

I'm learning so I will appreciate any help that you can provide :)

Comment: Thanks mate, I change my last line in the sass taks to:

 .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))

Works perfect now, thanks again

Could you explain me why I did need stream true? just so I know it by heart rather than second guess myself :)

Comment: in gulp task there should be a stream throught the pipeline. every pipe should return the stream object for pass the stream to next pipe.

at first version of your code; sync, broking the stream cycle because of reload method returns nothing. and gulp throwing an error for this reason. stream:true property try to inject the streams and returning the incoming stream back. this is it.

actually u can use sync.stream() instead of sync.reload(). or if u dont want to inject your styles u can apply like this example

https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/#gulp-reload